# How is this element bumped up on the page?

Tags: css

On this page (you will need to add a product to the cart to see the checkout fields): https://www.wptasty.com/checkout

The fieldset  element ("Credit Card Info") is sitting halfway outside its container (the grey background is the container):

[part of checkout form where legend is sitting halfway outside its container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YECpE.png)

I initially thought it was just some negative top margin, but I can't find any evidence of that. I thought maybe it was absolutely positioned, but can't find that, either.

Can you help me understand how it is positioned in this way so that I can undo it and move it back to being fully within its container?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Credit Card Info</legend>
        <input>A variety of inputs</input>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Edited to add HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Credit Card Info" is displayed inside a `legend` element and it's doing what `legend`s do inside a fieldset: it's displayed center-aligned inside the top border of its parent `fieldset`. That's the default display for `legend`, which is a bit of a special case in HTML.

You can position it using `float` or `absolute` positioning, but things like `display` won't work since `legend` is special.

Comment: Thank you for the help! That explains it. I didn't know that `legend` elements were treated special.